# Issue performing a Mapping on Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, dictionary, int, mapping

I'm trying to get this JavaScript to work.

Here the request: have to pass to another system the currency with the destination system id, not with my system id, for that I have to use the IsoCode from my system to map to the related id on the destination system.

```
function GetMappedCurrencyValue(CurrencyISO) {

  var mapCurrencyTable = [
    ["GBP", 1],
    ["EUR", 2],
    ["USD", 51],
    ["COP", 102],
    ["BRL", 104]
  ];

  return mapCurrencyTable[CurrencyISO - "GBP"][1];
}
```

When I'm trying to call the mapCurrencyTable function I'm getting the following error:

> CurrentISO - is undefined

I have in the principal function a variable to get the IsoCode from my currencies table which is call CurrentISO, and that is a global variable on that function.

Can anyone gives me a clue on what I'm missing in this map?

Comment: How `GetMappedCurrencyValue` is called

Comment: please add an example of a call of the function and the wanted result of it.

Comment: Your array does not contain an index *CurrencyISO - "GBP"*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just transform the table in an object and you won't need any function:

```js
var mapCurrencyTable = {
  "GBP" : 1,
  "EUR" : 2,
  "USD" : 51,
  "COP" : 102,
  "BRL" : 104
};

console.log(mapCurrencyTable['USD']);
```

If you really need to use an array, here is a way to convert the array to an object:

```js
var mapCurrencyTable = [
    ["GBP", 1],
    ["EUR", 2],
    ["USD", 51],
    ["COP", 102],
    ["BRL", 104]
];
  
var objTable = {};
  
mapCurrencyTable.map(cur=>objTable[cur[0]]=cur[1]);

console.log(objTable['COP']);
```

Comment: Hi Nelson, I do have to create a function to do this because I'm trying to send this on an XML request to another system, your share for me looks like the way to do it, but when I'm doing the calling to the function, it returns me [object Object]

`function GetMappedCurrencyValue(CurrencyISO) {
  
 var mapCurrencyTable = [
  ["GBP", 1],
  ["EUR", 2],
  ["USD", 51],
  ["COP", 102],
  ["BRL", 104]
 ];
 
 var objTable = {};
 
 mapCurrencyTable.map(cur=>objTable[cur[0]]=cur[1]);
 
 
 
 return objTable[];
}`

Comment: Sorry and thank you so much! i just add the `return objTable[CurrencyISO];` and works like a charm!

Comment: Glad I clould help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you want :

```
function GetMappedCurrencyValue(CurrencyISO) {

  var mapCurrencyTable = {
    "GBP" : 1,
    "EUR": 2,
    "USD": 51,
    "COP": 102,
    "BRL": 104
  };

  return CurrencyISO - mapCurrencyTable["GBP"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you wish to achieve from your presentation.

Perhaps you want to

```
return mapCurrencyTable[CurrencyISO][1];
```

from within your function, 
then to use the function do:

```
GetMappedCurrencyValue("GBP");
```